# Why can't I use plugin and jquery UI?

Tags: jquery

I started a web page containing a color box plugin. It does work, however, when I add ui elements(tabs), my plugin seems ot stop working. Returns an error  $(...).tabs is not a function. This error only appers when I am trying to get both working. When I remove the code for the tabs, the plugin is working fine. Any ideas?

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="proppagesstyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox\colorbox-master\colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="colorbox\colorbox-master\jquery.colorbox.js"></script>


<div id="tabs-1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Floor Plan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Map</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>
            Description
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>
            <img src="prop1Plan.jpg">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d39851.09199225635!2d0.061092186988258655!3d51.371935680859664!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47d8ab091574bbd7%3A0x12eb74ad89922e5b!2sOrpington!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1482163876019" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".group1").colorbox({ rel: 'gallery' });
    });
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $('#click').css({ "background-color": "#f00", "color": "#fff", "cursor": "inherit" }).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
        return false;
    });

    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        $("#tabs-1").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should look in to formatting your code correctly - it will make it much easier to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're adding a second version of jQuery after the first. This overwrites the previous `jQuery` instance which had jQueryUI methods applied to it.

To fix the problem simply remove the second reference to jQuery `1.10.2`. Only ever include one version of jQuery in a page.

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox\colorbox-master\colorbox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="proppagesstyle.css">

<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="colorbox\colorbox-master\jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that make sense.